# Nginx duplicating query string on redirect

Tags: linux, redirect, nginx, server, webserver

I am trying to redirect all traffic from urls that contain 'www.' to the similar url that does not contain it, but when I do so Nginx appends a duplicate query string at the end of the url.

For example, the user enters:

```
 www.website.com/test/?_id=12345
```

And they get redirected to:

```
website.com/test/?_id=12345?_id=12345
```

Here is my config:

```
server {
  server_name www.website.com;
  return 301 $scheme://website$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
    server_name website.com
    # actual server stuff
}
```

I have tried appending a '?' to the end of the redirect after the 'request_uri' portion because form what I have read that should work, but it didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config is invalid. You seem to have mixed up the syntax of `return` and `rewrite`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) for details.

The `$request_uri` variable already includes the query string, so this should work with `return`:

```
return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
```

The `rewrite` directive will append the query string unless a `?` is appended. It is possible to use a `rewrite` directive to accomplish the same function, but in this case it would be overkill.

As your config is invalid, `nginx` is still running with an earlier configuration, possibly an earlier experiment that placed `$request_uri` in a `rewrite` directive, hence the double query string.

Comment: Thanks, I think it was a weird combination of my browser caching the incorrect redirects and what you have said. I appreciate it.